# When adding a README for git purposes, what does the keyword 'touch' do in the '$ touch README' command?

Tags: macos, github, terminal

I'm trying to understand the keyword `touch` used in adding a README to Github repo in Mac.

```
$ touch README
```

this adds a blank file titled `README`. So what does touch really represent?
For example, in case of `$ subl README` - `subl` is going to launch sublime text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All touch does is update the file's timestamp (if the file exists), or creates an empty file with that name. See http://ss64.com/bash/touch.html

Comment: Thanks @alroc - that link also helped understand that 'touch' is a bash command.

Comment: `touch` isn't a part of bash, it is its own command-line program.